# calculated fields in Entity: Autowired is null

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have an `Entity`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orgtree")
public class OrganizationTree {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ORGANIZATION_ID")
    private String organizationId;

    @Column(name="ORGANIZATION_NAME")
    private String organizationName;

}
```

and a repository to provide REST access

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "organizationTree", path = "organizationTree")
public interface OrganizationTreeRepository extends JpaRepository<OrganizationTree,String> {
    @Query
    @RestResource(path = "findAll", rel = "findAll")
    List<OrganizationTree> findAll();
}
```

So far so good.

Now I want to add a calculated field to my entity

```
@Autowired
@Transient
private OrgTreeService orgTreeService;

@JsonSerialize
public Integer getPersonCount() {
    return orgTreeService.getPersonCount(organizationId);
}
```

Here I have several problems:

- orgTreeService is null
- people say that it's a bad practice to use a
  service in an Entity

What is the canonical solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution I found (or should I call it a hack) is the following:

I annotate a calculated field with a custom serializer:

```
@Formula(value = "ORGANIZATION_ID")
@JsonSerialize(using=JsonOrgPersonCountSerializer.class)
private String personCount;
```

In the serializer I compute the person's count:

```
public class JsonOrgPersonCountSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(String source, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider prov) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        gen.writeString("" + orgTreeService.getPersonCount(source));
    }

}
```

Another solution would be to use some kind of Data Transfer Object where I can call my service.